# Double integration an even function

Tags: calculus, multiple-integral

$\displaystyle{\int \int 1 dxdy }$ over the region $R$ where $R = \{(x,y):x^2+y^2=16\}$

The solution given in class went like this:

$\displaystyle{\int_{-4}^{4} \int_{x=-\sqrt{4-y^2}}^{x=\sqrt{4-y^2}}1dxdy} = 2\int_{0}^{4}\int_{x=0}^{x=\sqrt{4-y^2}}dxdy$

The other question went like this

$\displaystyle{\int \int (x^2+y^2-1) dxdy} $ over the region $R$ where $R = \{(x,y):x^2+y^2=16\}$

The solution for this problem went like this:

$\displaystyle{\int_{-4}^{4} \int_{x=-\sqrt{4-y^2}}^{x=\sqrt{4-y^2}}(x^2+y^2-1)dxdy = 4\int_{0}^{4}\int_{x=0}^{x=\sqrt{4-y^2}}(x^2+y^2-1)dxdy}$

Is this a typo or there is a logic behind this?

Comment: The first is wrong: you divide the integration domain in $4$ equal parts, where the function is identical ($f(-x,y)=f(x,y)$ and $f(x,-y)=f(x,y)$, where $f$ is the integrand), then the integral is multiplied by $4$, not $2$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut what happens when $f(-x,y)=f(x,y)$ then it gets multiplied by $2$ right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the integrand is even for the component $x$. That is, $$f(-x,y)=f(x,y).$$
With that you can justify converting the integral $\int_{-\sqrt{4-y^2}}^{\sqrt{4-y^2}}dx$ into $2\int^{\sqrt{4-y^2}}_{0}dx$.

On the other hand, the function $\int f(x,y)dx$ is even for the component $y$. That is,
$$\int f(x,-y)dx=\int f(x,y)dx.$$
This justifies splitting the other integral, $\int_{-4}^4$.

Comment: I have a doubt $\int_{-4}^{4} \int_{x=-\sqrt{4-y^2}}^{x=\sqrt{4-y^2}}f(x,y)dxdy = \int_{-4}^{4}(2\int_{x=0}^{x=\sqrt{4-y^2}}f(x,y)dxdy)$ If $\int_{x=0}^{x=\sqrt{4-y^2}} f(x,y)$ is not even wrt to $y$ then we can't multiply by $2$ right?

Comment: That's right, in that case you don't know if the integrand is symmetric.